# PyQt drops all of signals and slots after using chained invoke like pyObj.setupUi(parent)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

All of singals (for example textChanged in below codes) will be dropped and printDummy function will be silented once I used `DummyWidget().setupUi(mainWin)`, but everything will be working when I used `dw = DummyWidget(); dw.setupUi(main)`. I didn't see the specific difference in Python's syntax. Can anyone share any comment?

```
class DummyWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, parent=None):
        assert parent is not None
        self.parent = parent
        parent.resize(480, 320)
        self.DUMMY = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
        # parent.setCentralWidget(self.DUMMY)
        self.DUMMY.textChanged.connect(self.printDummy)
        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    def printDummy(self):
        print "DUMMY IN CLASS"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    def printDummy(*args):
        print "DUMMY"

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # mainWin = MainWindow()
    # edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    # edit.textChanged.connect(printDummy)
    # mainWin.setCentralWidget(edit)
    mainWin = QtGui.QDialog()
    # DummyWidget().setupUi(mainWin)
    dw = DummyWidget()
    dw.setupUi(mainWin)
    mainWin.show()
    # mainWin.open()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't keep a reference to the instance of `DummyWidget` it will be garbage collected, hence your slot would no longer exist.

If you do `DummyWidget.setupUi(parent)` you cannot store a reference (this line gives you the return value of `setupUi` which is `None`).

Comment: Thanks! You are correct. The slot object is not kept well in the new scope. I'll accept your answer.